# Design pattern for Spring Boot back end and Angular front end

Tags: angular, spring-boot, design-patterns

I have built an application that uses Spring Boot as back end and Angular as front end using APIs.

Spring Boot contains:

```
Dao
Controller
Entity
Service
```

and some classes.

After research I see that the design pattern for this structure is MVC (model view controller). But in this case view is in Angular.

What is the design pattern to use in this case, when we have back end and front end and relation between is using APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, considering the broader picture, the entire architecture follows a Client-Server pattern.

**Client: Angular App**

**Server: Backend Services**

The Server can also be invoked directly, in which case those will be other clients alongside Angular App.

Internal to Backend service, other design patterns can be observed as DAO pattern, Factory pattern, Observer etc, but that would depend on whether you have actually used them.